# EXC_BAD_SIGNAL during loading of nib file in iphone

Tags: iphone, exc-bad-access

I integrated facebook api in my application. I am storing all wall values in array and showing it in my tableview NIB file. But after logged in I am getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception in main.m in line this.

int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);

I am able to trace value. Here is my code of loading nib file.

```
facebookData=[[[[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:result]retain]autorelease];
Fave *bController = [[[Fave alloc] initWithNibName:@"Fave" bundle:nil]autorelease];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:bController animated:YES];
[bController release];
```

Here facebookdata is an array defined in main.m file. I am storing values of wall in this array and in next Fave nib file I am showing values from array. Why I am getting this error during loading of nib file.

Thanks in advance

Comment: @kay.. please don't see the question title. understand the logic. In my previous question i was getting problem with array init. and this thread I am having problem in main.m file.

Comment: @uvesten, I am guessing this problem is occuring in Fave class. It might be I am wrong with tablelist but I am not guessing where I did mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have autoreleased the Fave View Controller and again you have released it.
Dont do that

Do like this

```
Fave *bController = [[Fave alloc] initWithNibName:@"Fave" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:bController animated:YES];
[bController release];
```

Why are you retaining and also autoreleasing.. Thats bad.
just give like this

```
facebookData=[[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:result];
```

In future where you dont need facebookData then release it

Comment: I made changes at both places. but still same result. I am seeing this on console [Switching to process 2937 thread 0x207].

Comment: Should I give autorelease of tablelist (NSMutableArray *tableList) in fave class. ?

Comment: Thanks. It is working now. It was problem with my tablelist. I release it in dealloc function. Now this is working.

Answer (score 1):

Please do your code like this...

```
facebookData=[[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:result];
Fave *bController = [[Fave alloc] initWithNibName:@"Fave" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:bController animated:YES];
[bController release];
```

You can only release `[bController release]` if your Fave Controller does not contain any memory leaks...

and you are retaining the array and making it autorelease, this is bad habbit..Please make it change..

Happy Coding...